# Kotlin structured concurrency : blocking a call when a java library runs in a separate thread

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

So, this is the problem :

My application calls a `functionA` in a third party library which creates its own thread and calls back the caller in that thread. What I want to do is call that `functionA` from a function in my app and wait until the callback has been called and then exit my function. I tried to use `runBlocking`, `withContext` etc., to no avail.

Below is a code snippet.

```
  fun appFunction(context: Context) {
    // call library function `functionA` which calls back the success and failure callbacks in a separate java thread.
    runBlocking {
      launch { functionA({ Timber.i("Call Success") }, { Timber.e(it) }) }
      joinAll()
    }
  }
```

I want the app function to return only after the callback method finishes executing. I was thinking using a launch would make all threads created inside the java library would be part of the same coroutine scope and joinAll() would wait on that. Obviously, I was wrong.

Is this something that could be achieved? If so, how?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard way of doing this with coroutines is by using either [suspendCoroutine()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.coroutines/suspend-coroutine.html) or [suspendCancellableCoroutine()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/suspend-cancellable-coroutine.html). They both suspend execution waiting to be resumed (for example from a callback) and the difference is that the latter additionally supports cancelling while waiting. I suggest reading docs for the cancellable variant, as docs are much better there.

Example with `suspendCoroutine()`:

```kotlin
suspendCoroutine<Unit> { continuation ->
    functionA(
        { continuation.resume(Unit) },
        { continuation.resumeWithException(it) }
    )
}
```

Note that to use above, your function has to be a suspend function. In your question `appFunction()` is a regular function, so it can't suspend or wait for anything. Technically, you can use `runBlocking()`, but if you plan to block threads then I think it doesn't make too much sense to use coroutines - you can just use callbacks.

Comment: This is an excellent direction. Thank you. I shall let you know my observations after I try it out.